# How to make the object with random images?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, game-development

I have hard time with dealing with materials, to make my game more dynamic i want to apply some skins on my objects..
I tried to make size of materials on mesh renderer to 3 and apply 3 materials,but it doesn't look good because I must to turn off third material , or second and third need to stay active..
My first material is colour and it must stay the same.

What i mean is easy to say with photo ..

This is my cube object with one material as default looks perfect:
[image]

This is what i want to look when i add second material:
[image]

This is when i add third material the second is still active and i only need to be active second or third not active second and third

[image]

So the problem is in my case that I want only two materials active on my objects 
in my example first one always need to be active named in my photos "New Material 2"

then I need one more active on my case only second or third, I have problem because all materials are active and then my objects don't look how i want to them to look..
I thought to make random script attach it to every single object make 10 materials in mesh and activate first one always and pick random number from 1 to 10 and activate only that one on start.

Also in unity -> Unity complains when i add second material and i need it for skin maybe there is better or proper way to do the same .. But I found only this solution ..

So my question is how I can skin my cube and add to it multiple skins and choose them randomly where the default material or color will always be active.

Thank you so much community I don't know what would I do without you!

Comment: So why do you add the third? you can replace the second one. just do `materials[1] = new_random_material`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a simple component for that:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Renderer))]
public class RandomMaterial : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Now in this list add all materials that shall be
    // options for the random selection
    [SerializeField] private Material[] materials;

    // Either already reference this in the Inspector
    // or get it later on runtime
    [SerializeField] private Renderer renderer;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!renderer) renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();

        // A little check
        if(materials.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("No Materials referenced! -> Ignored", this);
            return;
        }

        // get random index for material
        // first parameter is inclusive - second is exlusive
        // => index will be between 0 and materials.Length -1
        var index = Random.Range(0, materials.Length);
        var selectedMaterial = materials[index];

        // create a new array for 2 Materials
        // you can't simply assign renderer.materials[1]
        // because you don't know if there already are two spots
        // available in that array
        // also makes sure there no other materials left but only those
        // two you will add in the next lines
        var rendererMaterials = new Material[2];
        // keep the first (main) material
        rendererMaterials[0] = renderer.material;
        // set selected material as second material
        rendererMaterials[1] = selectedMaterial;
        // assign the new materials to the object
        renderer.materials = rendererMaterials;
    }
}
```

Depending on your needs you might also want to consider using [`renderer.sharedMaterials`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sharedMaterials.html) and accordingly `rendererMaterials[0] = renderer.sharedMaterial;` in order to use the global Materials instead of instanced ones. That means if you later changed the `renderer.sharedMaterial|s` properties it will affact every randerer in the scene using that shared Material. Otherwise if you change the `Renderer.material|s` properties it creates a new Material instance which only affects this single `Renderer`.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me out,finally i have different materials, now my question is , is that good approach for graphics and game optimisation because my unity complains when i add more then one material to it.. I don't know why. thank you so much for your solution.
what is the best way to apply this solution to 10 objects, add to every object script and attach 10 materials to get the random or to make one gameobject and somehow populate with random materials each one..

Comment: If you make e.g. one Prefab with this script and spawn it 10 times .. it everytime takes a random material. It **can** result in 10 different objects or in 10 times the same though both of  those cases are quite unlikely to happen. If you rather want them all being different you can allways after selecting one material remove it from the list so it is not available to other instances anymore